# Create WPF TreeView from array

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, treeview

I am struggling with this and hope someone can help me solving.
I have an array of string that are directories. This is an example of my array:

- c:\temp\freigabe
- c:\temp\ftptest
- c:\temp\ftptest\testen
- c:\temp\in
- c:\temp\in - Kopie
- c:\temp\in - Kopie\1
- c:\temp\in - Kopie\1\yyy
- c:\temp\in - Kopie\1\yyy\yyyyy
- c:\temp\in - Kopie\2
- c:\temp\in2
- c:\temp\ipadb
- c:\temp\out
- c:\temp\out2
- c:\temp\Processes2
- c:\temp\Processes2\Kassenbelege
- c:\temp\Processes2\Kassenbelege\images
- c:\temp\Processes2\Posteingang
- c:\temp\Processes2\Posteingang\images
- c:\temp\Processes2\Rechnungen
- c:\temp\Processes2\Rechnungen\images
- c:\temp\Processes2\Rechnungen\images\backup
- c:\temp\test

I want to fill a WPF TreeView from this array. The TreeView should show the folders like in an explorer view.

Thank you.
Marco

Comment: What have you already tried?  A TreeView should be able to bind to a linear collection without any issues (I'd recommend using an ObservableCollection).  Do you have any experience with WPF data binding?

Comment: Hi Craig, I am not very experienced with WPF. What I have tried to split each folder and compare the strings. Then adding the strings as new items. But this is not a good way I guess. So data binding seems to be a better way. Perhaps you have some code snipped where I can follow your idea?

Comment: Data binding is fundamental to WPF.  If you don't have any experience with it, I'd suggest doing some background reading and trying a toy problem to build some experience.  I'll still post an answer that has some details, but it's assuming a baseline level of knowledge of WPF.

Comment: I will note that I find documentation that goes beyond the basics in WPF to be very spotty, and I'm often reduced to cargo-culting things to make them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, here is how I solved it.
I created a TreeView in XAML that looks like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvw" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="798" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:_Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubFolders}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=FullPath}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In the code I created one class that holds the folders, the structure is build by the treeview itself:

```
Public Class _Folder
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property FullPath As String
    Public ReadOnly Property SubFolders As List(Of _Folder) = New List(Of _Folder)()
End Class
```

The following code iterates through the list (of String) with my folders:

```
Dim lstFolders As New List(Of _Folder)
Dim RootFolder As New _Folder

For Each f In _items
    If f.Contains("\\") Then f = f.Replace("\\", ":")
    Dim drive = f.Split(":")(0)
    Dim path = f.Split(":")(1)

    'If String.IsNullOrEmpty(drive) Then Continue For
    RootFolder.Name = drive

    Dim charSeparators As Char() = New Char() {System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}
    Dim pathSplit() As String = path.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim currentFolder As _Folder = RootFolder
    For Each level In pathSplit
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(level) Then Continue For
        Dim foundFolder = (From x In currentFolder.SubFolders Where x.Name = level Select x).FirstOrDefault
        If foundFolder Is Nothing Then
            foundFolder = New _Folder
            foundFolder.Name = level
            If f.StartsWith(":") Then 'Netzwerkpfad
                foundFolder.FullPath = (f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(level)) & level).Replace(":", "\\")
            Else 'Pfad mit Laufwerksbuchstaben
                foundFolder.FullPath = f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(level)) & level
            End If

            currentFolder.SubFolders.Add(foundFolder)
        End If
        currentFolder = foundFolder
    Next

Next

lstFolders.Add(RootFolder)
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF works around the idea of data binding.  Assuming that you have a collection, you are expected to bind the TreeView to the item collection.  If you have, for example:

```vb
Class TreeViewItem
    Public Property DisplayText As String
End Class
```

And if you have a TreeView defined like this:

```xml
<TreeView Name="FileListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Then you can explicitly bind the collection, e.g.

```vb
Class MyWindow
    Dim _items As New ObservableCollection(Of TreeViewItem)
    '...

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        '...
        FileListView.DataContext = _items
        '...
    End Sub

    '...
End Class
```

I think you may need to define an item template for the TreeView so that it knows how to display your items as well, which would be something like this inside the TreeView definition in xaml:

```xml
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

In this case, I manually set the datacontext on the TreeView, but the more common approach in WPF would be to have a datacontext for the form as a whole, and then bind the treeview to a property on the form-level datacontext type.

Comment: Hello Craig, this is very helpful so far. Thank you.
I have now i mplemented the ObservableCollection and I fill this with the list of TreeViewItems. 
Works. But the result TreeView is not hierarchical. It just shows all the entries in the ObservableCollection as flat view.

Comment: You'll need to process your list into a hierarchical collection in order to have it displayed that way in a TreeView (see the other answer).  You may find this documentation page to be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-bind-a-treeview-to-data-that-has-an-indeterminable-depth?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score -1):

TreeViews require a hierarchical structure, not a flat list of items.

Something like

```
public class Folder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Folder> SubFolders { get; } = new List<Folder>();
}
```

which you will have to create for each item to be displayed.

The `ItemsSource` property of the `TreeView` control can then be assigned (or bound to) a collection of Folder items, which would form the root nodes of the tree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peregrine, but can you give me some more help on that. I am farly new to WPF and I have no clue how to do. Within Winforms I have not a problem and my code ist working fine, but with WPF I am struggling.

Comment: This is not accurate in my experience.  I have successfully bound a treeview to a linear ObservableCollection.